# Web API to call a stored procedure to insert/update DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have been working on creating the Web API that accepts the input parameter and calls a Stored Procedure passing the input parameter we received that insert/updates the Account Table in the Database. Now that is perfectly , but my API also need to select the record which was updated/inserted and return them as response

```
   public class ProjectNameCreationController : ApiController
   {
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string Account)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Account))
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(new { error = "Input parameters cannot be Empty or NULL" });
        }
       string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString;
       SqlConnection DbConnection = new SqlConnection(strcon);
       DbConnection.Open();

       SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[usp_InserUpadte]", DbConnection);
       command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

       //create type table
       DataTable table = new DataTable();
       table.Columns.Add("AccountID", typeof(string));
       table.Rows.Add(Account);

       SqlParameter parameter = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@account_TT", table);
       parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
       parameter.TypeName = "account_TT";
       command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Now I am not sure if we will able to select the record that was now  insert/updated as part of the Stored Procedure or will I have to create a Query seperately like below

```
       string strQuery = "select AccountID,CounterSeq from Account where AccountID = @accountID ";
       var cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountID",Account);
```

Because I will have to Return the response as AccountID-CounterSeq (Eg: IT-1) when the API is called like http://localhost/api/ProjectNameCreation?Account=IT. How can I deal with this. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: are you using SQL Server?

Comment: This is not the efficient way to deal with the data when you are working on a web api. You may consider using [Entity Framework](https://www.asp.net/entity-framework) for database operations.

Comment: Do I create the Entity Framework for the stored Procedure?

Comment: Could your proc simply not perform the update and then return the result back? So instead of `ExecuteNonQuery` use `ExecuteReader` reading the result back from the proc and sending it back in the response.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your procedure as below it will return a record of last inserted or updated.

```
 **--for insert** 
    IF @StatementType = 'Insert'
    BEGIN
    insert into Account (first_name,last_name,salary,city) values( @first_name,  @last_name,  @salary, @city) 
    --below line to return last inserted record
    select * from Account where accountid= SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    END
    **--for Update** 
    IF @StatementType = 'Update'
    BEGIN
    UPDATE Account SET
                First_name =  @first_name, last_name = @last_name, salary = @salary,
                city = @city
          WHERE accountid= @accountid
    --below line to return last Updated record
    select * from account where accountid = @accountid
```